# esutil install fails without any clear error

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, pip

I'm trying to install the python package esutil. The github repo is available here: https://github.com/esheldon/esutil

I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu 15.04. Installing esutil fails with both:
sudo pip3 install esutil 
sudo python3 setup.py (in the appropriate folder)

I can install other packages and my python setup seems otherwise well behaved.

Here's the error message for the pip install. I've spent a long time trying to parse it but I can't seem to find any 'fatal' errors. Any ideas what the cause is?

```
sudo pip3 install esutil
[sudo] password for sam: 
Downloading/unpacking esutil
  Downloading esutil-v0.5.2.tar.gz (714kB): 714kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-c16wv522/esutil/setup.py) egg_info for package esutil

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from esutil)
Installing collected packages: esutil
  Running setup.py install for esutil
    building 'esutil.recfile._records' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Iesutil/include -Iesutil/htm -Iesutil/htm/htm_src -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c esutil/recfile/records.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/recfile/records.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from /home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804:0,
                     from /home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                     from /home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from esutil/recfile/records.hpp:9,
                     from esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1:
    /home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^
    In file included from esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1:0:
    esutil/recfile/records.hpp:33:1: warning: missing terminating " character
     "
     ^
    esutil/recfile/records.hpp:90:1: warning: missing terminating " character
     ");
     ^
    esutil/recfile/records.hpp:105:3: warning: missing terminating " character
       "
       ^
    esutil/recfile/records.hpp:132:56: warning: missing terminating " character
           res = robj.Read(rows=rows2get, fields=fields2get)");
                                                            ^
    esutil/recfile/records.hpp:142:3: warning: missing terminating " character
       "
       ^
    esutil/recfile/records.hpp:169:3: warning: missing terminating " character
       ");
       ^
    esutil/recfile/records.hpp:178:3: warning: missing terminating " character
       "
       ^
    esutil/recfile/records.hpp:182:3: warning: missing terminating " character
       ");
       ^
    In file included from /usr/include/locale.h:28:0,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.9/clocale:42,
                     from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/c++locale.h:41,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/localefwd.h:40,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:41,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                     from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                     from esutil/recfile/records.hpp:2,
                     from esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1:
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In constructor ‘Records::Records(PyObject*, const char*, PyObject*, PyObject*, long long int, int)’:
    /home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1708:35: error: returning a value from a constructor
     #define NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL NULL
                                       ^
    /home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1713:151: note: in expansion of macro ‘NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL’
     #define import_array() {if (_import_array() < 0) {PyErr_Print(); PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"); return NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL; } }
                                                                                                                                                           ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:10:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘import_array’
      import_array();
      ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::GetFptr(PyObject*, const char*)’:
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1013:29: error: ‘PyString_Check’ was not declared in this scope
      if (PyString_Check(file_obj)) {
                                 ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1015:41: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope
       string fstr=PyString_AsString(file_obj);
                                             ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1023:34: error: ‘PyFile_Check’ was not declared in this scope
      } else if (PyFile_Check(file_obj)) {
                                      ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1025:33: error: ‘PyFile_AsFile’ was not declared in this scope
       mFptr = PyFile_AsFile(file_obj);
                                     ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::ProcessDelim(PyObject*)’:
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1042:31: error: ‘PyString_Check’ was not declared in this scope
       if (PyString_Check(delim_obj)) {
                                   ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1043:40: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope
        mDelim = PyString_AsString(delim_obj);
                                            ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::SubDtype(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject**, std::vector<long long int>&)’:
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1099:39: error: ‘PyString_Check’ was not declared in this scope
      } else if (PyString_Check(subnamesobj)) {
                                           ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘PyObject* Records::FieldDescriptorAsTuple(PyArray_Descr*, const char*)’:
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1231:28: error: ‘PyString_FromString’ was not declared in this scope
        PyString_FromString(name) );
                                ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1249:46: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope
        <<PyString_AsString(PyTuple_GetItem(tup,0))<<"'"
                                                  ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::ListStringMatch(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, PyObject*, std::vector<long long int>&)’:
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1319:28: error: ‘PyString_Check’ was not declared in this scope
        if (!PyString_Check(item)) {
                                ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1323:39: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope
         string ts = PyString_AsString(item);
                                           ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::PyDictPrintKeys(PyObject*)’:
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1419:50: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope
       cout<<"key["<<i<<"] = "<<PyString_AsString(item)<<endl;
                                                      ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::CopyDescrOrderedNames(PyArray_Descr*)’:
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1444:38: error: ‘PyString_AS_STRING’ was not declared in this scope
       string tname=PyString_AS_STRING(tmp);
                                          ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::CopyDescrOrderedOffsets(PyArray_Descr*)’:
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1494:42: error: ‘PyInt_Check’ was not declared in this scope
                         if (PyInt_Check(shape) ) {
                                              ^
    esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1504:60: error: ‘PyInt_AsLong’ was not declared in this scope
                                 mDims[i][ii] = PyInt_AsLong(tmp);
                                                                ^
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-c16wv522/esutil/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-q8_g976u-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/io.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/oracle_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/numpy_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/misc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/json_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/plotting.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/sqlite_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/random.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/sfile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/algorithm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/fits.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/stomp_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/xmltools.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/hdfs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/wcsutil.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/coords.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/ostools.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

copying esutil/cosmology_purepy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/recfile

copying esutil/recfile/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/recfile

copying esutil/recfile/Util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/recfile

copying esutil/recfile/records.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/recfile

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/cosmology

copying esutil/cosmology/cosmology.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/cosmology

copying esutil/cosmology/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/cosmology

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/htm

copying esutil/htm/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/htm

copying esutil/htm/htmc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/htm

copying esutil/htm/unit_tests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/htm

copying esutil/htm/htm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/htm

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/stat

copying esutil/stat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/stat

copying esutil/stat/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/stat

copying esutil/stat/chist.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/stat

copying esutil/stat/unit_tests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/stat

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/integrate

copying esutil/integrate/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/integrate

copying esutil/integrate/cgauleg.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/integrate

copying esutil/integrate/util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/integrate

running build_ext

building 'esutil.recfile._records' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/recfile

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Iesutil/include -Iesutil/htm -Iesutil/htm/htm_src -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c esutil/recfile/records.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/esutil/recfile/records.o

cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++

In file included from /home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804:0,

                 from /home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,

                 from /home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,

                 from esutil/recfile/records.hpp:9,

                 from esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1:

/home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]

 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \

  ^

In file included from esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1:0:

esutil/recfile/records.hpp:33:1: warning: missing terminating " character

 "

 ^

esutil/recfile/records.hpp:90:1: warning: missing terminating " character

 ");

 ^

esutil/recfile/records.hpp:105:3: warning: missing terminating " character

   "

   ^

esutil/recfile/records.hpp:132:56: warning: missing terminating " character

       res = robj.Read(rows=rows2get, fields=fields2get)");

                                                        ^

esutil/recfile/records.hpp:142:3: warning: missing terminating " character

   "

   ^

esutil/recfile/records.hpp:169:3: warning: missing terminating " character

   ");

   ^

esutil/recfile/records.hpp:178:3: warning: missing terminating " character

   "

   ^

esutil/recfile/records.hpp:182:3: warning: missing terminating " character

   ");

   ^

In file included from /usr/include/locale.h:28:0,

                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/clocale:42,

                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.9/bits/c++locale.h:41,

                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/localefwd.h:40,

                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:41,

                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,

                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,

                 from esutil/recfile/records.hpp:2,

                 from esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1:

esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In constructor ‘Records::Records(PyObject*, const char*, PyObject*, PyObject*, long long int, int)’:

/home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1708:35: error: returning a value from a constructor

 #define NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL NULL

                                   ^

/home/sam/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1713:151: note: in expansion of macro ‘NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL’

 #define import_array() {if (_import_array() < 0) {PyErr_Print(); PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ImportError, "numpy.core.multiarray failed to import"); return NUMPY_IMPORT_ARRAY_RETVAL; } }

                                                                                                                                                       ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:10:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘import_array’

  import_array();

  ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::GetFptr(PyObject*, const char*)’:

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1013:29: error: ‘PyString_Check’ was not declared in this scope

  if (PyString_Check(file_obj)) {

                             ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1015:41: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope

   string fstr=PyString_AsString(file_obj);

                                         ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1023:34: error: ‘PyFile_Check’ was not declared in this scope

  } else if (PyFile_Check(file_obj)) {

                                  ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1025:33: error: ‘PyFile_AsFile’ was not declared in this scope

   mFptr = PyFile_AsFile(file_obj);

                                 ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::ProcessDelim(PyObject*)’:

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1042:31: error: ‘PyString_Check’ was not declared in this scope

   if (PyString_Check(delim_obj)) {

                               ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1043:40: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope

    mDelim = PyString_AsString(delim_obj);

                                        ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::SubDtype(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject**, std::vector<long long int>&)’:

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1099:39: error: ‘PyString_Check’ was not declared in this scope

  } else if (PyString_Check(subnamesobj)) {

                                       ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘PyObject* Records::FieldDescriptorAsTuple(PyArray_Descr*, const char*)’:

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1231:28: error: ‘PyString_FromString’ was not declared in this scope

    PyString_FromString(name) );

                            ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1249:46: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope

    <<PyString_AsString(PyTuple_GetItem(tup,0))<<"'"

                                              ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::ListStringMatch(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, PyObject*, std::vector<long long int>&)’:

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1319:28: error: ‘PyString_Check’ was not declared in this scope

    if (!PyString_Check(item)) {

                            ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1323:39: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope

     string ts = PyString_AsString(item);

                                       ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::PyDictPrintKeys(PyObject*)’:

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1419:50: error: ‘PyString_AsString’ was not declared in this scope

   cout<<"key["<<i<<"] = "<<PyString_AsString(item)<<endl;

                                                  ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::CopyDescrOrderedNames(PyArray_Descr*)’:

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1444:38: error: ‘PyString_AS_STRING’ was not declared in this scope

   string tname=PyString_AS_STRING(tmp);

                                      ^
p
esutil/recfile/records.cpp: In member function ‘void Records::CopyDescrOrderedOffsets(PyArray_Descr*)’:

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1494:42: error: ‘PyInt_Check’ was not declared in this scope

                     if (PyInt_Check(shape) ) {

                                          ^

esutil/recfile/records.cpp:1504:60: error: ‘PyInt_AsLong’ was not declared in this scope

                             mDims[i][ii] = PyInt_AsLong(tmp);

                                                            ^

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-c16wv522/esutil/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-q8_g976u-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-c16wv522/esutil
Storing debug log for failure in /home/sam/.pip/pip.log
```